# Finding amplitude of sine wave from known arc length and period/wavelength

Tags: calculus, integration

What would be the amplitude of a sine wave when its arc length and period are known.

A sine function can be written as,

$$y = a_0 sin\frac{2{\pi}}{L}x $$

So I know a relation to calculate the arc length as,

$$ Z = \int_0^L \sqrt{1+\bigg( \frac{dy}{dx} \bigg)^2}dx$$

$$ Z = \frac{2L}{\pi} \sqrt{1+\frac{2{\pi}a_0}{L}} \int_0^{{\pi}/2}\sqrt{1-k^2sin^2z}dz$$
where $k^2= \frac{\big(\frac{2{\pi}a_0}{L}\big)^2}{1+\big(\frac{2{\pi}a_0}{L}\big)^2}$

But in present case, I know Z $i.e.$ arc length and L $i.e.$ wavelength. I want to find $a_0$ i.e. the amplitude of sine wave.

Can someone suggest some method or formulation for this ? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am afraid you are only left with a numerical solution

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would approach the problem. Starting with your

$$y = a \sin\frac{2{\pi}}{L}x,\quad x\in[0,L]$$

let $\theta=\frac{2{\pi}}{L}x,\quad \theta\in[0,2\pi]$. Then the arc length is given by

$$
\begin{align}
s
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\bigg( \frac{dy}{dx} \bigg)^2}~d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+a^2\cos^2\theta}~d\theta\\
&=2\left[\text{E}(-a^2)+\sqrt{1+a^2}~\text{E}\left(\frac{a^2}{1+a^2} \right) \right]
\end{align}
$$

where $\text{E}$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind. (This solution was obtained with Mathematica.) Clearly, we cannot find an explicit expression for $a(s)$; a numerical solution is required. To that end, I ran solutions for random values of $a$ to determine $s$ and then verified by determining $a$ by numerical means from the above solution. The equation shown above for $s(a)$ is correct.